# What are the rules for when to use commas inside parenthesis?

Tags: punctuation, commas, parentheses

I know sometimes a comma is used after the parenthesis, sometimes it's used before the parenthesis, and sometimes no comma used at all. What I don't understand is how to know when to use which. If someone could explain, with example sentences, I'd very much appreciate it.